# Cognos passing a value to all prompts

Tags: javascript, jquery, prompt, cognos-bi, cognos-10

So I am using jQuery in my reports and I have a suite of reports that all load thanks to jQuery all at once so the customer feels like the transitions are faster because they don't have to wait between each click. I want to be able to have all reports change based off of a prompt the customer uses. So if they select a specific day, all of the reports in the suite will change to that day. Or if they have a specific area they select, all of the reports go to that area. This will make it so the customer doesn't have to load the parameters in the prompt for each report. I am wonderin if there is a way to do this. I have looked and haven't found anything.

Edit..
So in my report that houses all of the iframes and the value prompt that I have named changeMonth I have this JS

```
<script>
var report = cognos.Report.getReport("_THIS_");
var radio = report.prompt.getControlByName('monthChange');

var currentRadioValue = radio.getValues()[0]; //Get initial value object

radio.setValidator(validateRadio); //Define function to validate prompt

function validateRadio(values) {
if (values && values.length > 0 && values[0].use != currentRadioValue.use) { //Only do anything if control has value and has changed
    currentRadioValue = values[0]; //Assign new value for later comparison
    for (var i=0; i<window.frames.length; i++) { //Loop through all iFrames
             window.frames[i].changeValue(values[0].use); //Call the changeValue     function passing in the radio button value
    }
 }
return true; //Indicates the prompt is valid
}
</script>
```

In the reports that I want iframed in I have a value prompt that is a drop down list with this code in an HTML tag.

```
<script>
function changeValue(str){
var report = cognos.Report.getReport("_THIS_"); //Grab a handle for the report
var control = report.prompt.getControlByName('monthChange'); //Grab a handle for the    prompt control
control.addValues([{"use":str,"display":str}]); //Change the prompt to the passed in value
report.sendRequest(cognos.Report.Action.REPROMPT); //Reprompt the page
}
</script>
```

They were both drop down lists if that matters. I see that you listed them as radio buttons so I will try that here in a moment and let you know if that changed anything. But how I have it setup, is there something else i should be doing?

Comment: Where are your reports running? Report Studio? Workspace? Can you provide some more details? I've done extensive work with JavaScript in Cognos but would need more information to help you.

Comment: @Johnsonium it will all be done in report studio. I have am trying to make it work as we speak. So I have two iFrames setup and I want a prompt to drive both of those iframes. In the iframes I have crosstabs. So if I change the month in the prompt it will change it in both iframes

Comment: So, you have a Report Studio report containing a bunch of iFrames, each with their own Report Studio report. Is this correct? Also, can you indicate which version of Cognos you are running?

Comment: @Johnsonium I am using 10.2.1 and yes how I have it setup currently is each report is iframed in and they are linked to a tab at the top that is run by jQuery code. So what happens is when the report is ran all of the reports run at the same time so going from tab to tab there isn't any waiting because everything has already loaded. Where as before it would load as you went to each tab. So what the customer wants is to be able to select the value prompt up top to drive all of the iframes to change the month that they want to view. I have found some jquery dropdowns that may work not sure yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by creating a JavaScript function in each child report which changes a hidden prompt value which the query depends on and then reprompts the page. Here is the portion of the code that needs to be in every child object:

**Child Report(s) Code**

```
<script>
function changeValue(str){
    var report = cognos.Report.getReport("_THIS_"); //Grab a handle for the report
    var control = report.prompt.getControlByName('controlname'); //Grab a handle for the prompt control
    control.addValues([{"use":str,"display":str}]); //Change the prompt to the passed in value
    report.sendRequest(cognos.Report.Action.REPROMPT); //Reprompt the page
}
</script>
```

This utilizes the Cognos JavaScript Prompt API added in Cognos version 10.2. The functions getReport, getControlByName, addValues, and sendRequest are all functions provided by Cognos to make working with prompts in JavaScript easier. There's more info here:

[Cognos JavaScript Prompt API documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.2.0.doc/c_prmpt_api_overview.html?lang=en)

In the container report I created a Cognos radio button value prompt. I coded the JavaScript to leverage the built-in onchange validation hook provided by Cognos in the API to run code when the radio button has changed. The code loops through all iFrames and calls the function defined above in each child report passing in the value of the radio button selected.

**Container Report Code**

```
<script>
var report = cognos.Report.getReport("_THIS_");
var radio = report.prompt.getControlByName('radio');

var currentRadioValue = radio.getValues()[0]; //Get initial value object

radio.setValidator(validateRadio); //Define function to validate prompt

function validateRadio(values) {
    if (values && values.length > 0 && values[0].use != currentRadioValue.use) { //Only do anything if control has value and has changed
        currentRadioValue = values[0]; //Assign new value for later comparison
        for (var i=0; i<window.frames.length; i++) { //Loop through all iFrames
                 window.frames[i].changeValue(values[0].use); //Call the changeValue function passing in the radio button value
        }
    }
    return true; //Indicates the prompt is valid
}
</script>
```

Note that in the above code the strings 'controlname' and 'radio' correspond to the Name property of the prompt controls in question. By default Cognos does not give prompt controls a name. Thus, you have to supply the name after creation. Whatever names you give them the script has to be adjusted accordingly to allow JavaScript to access their Cognos Prompt API objects.

This technique can be modified to take input from any of the variety of prompt controls available in Cognos. Additionally, in theory, the container doesn't even have to be Cognos at all. It could be a standalone Web page with controls that call the JavaScript functions in the iFrames when standard HTML onchange events fire. The only caveat is due to security restrictions browsers do not allow calling of functions within iFrames from containers that have a different domain than the iFrame. This is something to consider when designing a solution.

Comment: So i tried what you have listed. I put the child into the reports that will be iFramed in and the container in the report with the prompt. I put a value prompt in the child report with it giving a month in the prompt. I named it pMonth. I then went to the Container report and named the prompt that should be driving everything and when I run my report it doesn't change the iframe. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I studied that API that you linked and it helps but I still am a little fuzzy on how to implement everything. Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The key things to check is making sure you change the getControlByName function's parameters to match the name property of the prompts you created both in the container and the child reports. Note that you have to specify the 'Name' property of each prompt, not the 'Parameter' property. Those are two different things. The JavaScript API finds the objects on your report by looking for the specified name ('radio' and 'controlname' in my code above).

Comment: I have changed the name of each of the prompts under the name property. I changed them from pMonth cause that was the parameter to changeMonth look up at my edit that I will make here in a moment with all of the code and where I have it and maybe you can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Did my code in my edit help? I have been playing with this since yesterday all day and I still can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Your code looks correct. From a Cognos JavaScript prompt API standpoint it shouldn't matter whether you use a drop-down, list or radio button group. The way the JavaScript works with the prompt objects is the same. Can you look at the browser console when you run the report? It often will provide useful error information. You can access the console in most browsers by hitting F12.

Comment: I am getting one error, it is "Unable to get the value of the property 'getValues': object is null or undefined".

Comment: Make sure that your HTML object containing the JavaScript is always at the very bottom of the page. Cognos renders things top to bottom. Thus, if you try to reference a prompt that appears below the JavaScript it won't yet exist and you'll get the error you describe.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help and bearing with me. I put the html tags in the bottom of the container and the child. I run the report and change the date in the prompt in the container report and it won't change the date in the child report. It defaults to august in the iframe and it stays in August in the crosstab that is being iframed in. Could it be that my company can disable the API for the prompts? if not then is there anything else you would recommend?

Comment: Are you still getting the error after moving the HTML to the bottom? At this point, the only thing I can recommend is standard JavaScript troubleshooting. Put console.log('message'); lines in the JavaScript (where 'message' is a contextual message) and see if it gets output to the console. Work your way through the code until you find where it's failing. Also, you can often run JavaScript commands interactively in the browser console. Try running some of the key commands manually. For instance the changeValue() function in the child reports.

Comment: Yeah the HTML tags are at the bottom of each report. I will give that a go and thank you again for all of your help

Comment: So after playing around with what you provided for a little bit. We were able to get it to work without having to trouble shoot at all. we just created a different report and followed your instructions from scratch rather than incorporating it with an existing one and it worked. Thank you so much, now we know how to use it we can make it work for us.

Comment: Alright I have one last question for you. So when I create the report everything runs just fine. I have these top links that the customer can hover over and it will expand certain reports. Every time I add those top links to the reports my prompts stop working but when I remove them they work just fine. Any ideas? the top links are being run by jquery and it seems that the jquery breaks the other js.

Comment: I've been experimenting with Cognos and JQuery recently and ran into some strange issues at times. Can you look at the console and see if there is an error?

Comment: So after playing around with it, the jQuery seems to be causing the problems and I am not sure why. It says that "Object doesn't support property or method" and it is pointing to something in my jquery. It works when I am using the jquery in another report that has JS in it, but it isn't working in this report for some reason. When I remove it though it works with no problems. I am going to continue to do my ts cause I need this but if you have any ideas it would be greatly appreciated. and all of your help up to this point is appreciated.

Comment: Like I'm said, I'm new using jQuery in Cognos. I've avoided frameworks because I wanted to know the base level code before I explored higher-level abstractions such as jQuery. So far, using jQuery in Cognos has been a bit temperamental. I think you are seeing that yourself. There are some peculiarities in Cognos regarding object state that might be tripping up jQuery. As I gain insight I'm going to share it with the community. I'm starting a Cognos developer blog, which I won't promote here, for that purpose.

Comment: So I was able to get all of these to work just like how I want them to work but I have one more question that I am hoping you will be able to answer cause I can't figure it out. Is there a way to pass several prompts. So if I have two or five different prompts driving all of my iFrames is it possible to have them up there? The first prompt is driving month, the next prompt would be driving a measure and the one after that might be driving an area. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. There's two ways to go. Have a change in any prompt immediately force a refresh of each child report to reflect the new value. In that scenario, you could just replicate what was already described, once for each prompt value. The second approach would be to not refresh the child reports until the user clicked on a prompt button of some sort. In that case you could build a single function in each child report that receives the values from each prompt as parameters, changes the associated prompt value and refreshes the page.